# Cscope relative path with parent directory display error

Tags: vim, cscope

I am creating a cscope database from cscope.files which has reference to files in current and parent directories, say the cscope.files content be

`foo\file1.c
..\..\foo1\file2.c`

When I search for a text/variable from cscope input field, the display screen does not shows the parent path entries, say it displays

`0 file1.c text`

`2 file1.c text`

But if I did a selection of `1` it is jumping to parent path entry in `file2.c`. I tried creating the cscope database with absolute path by providing `-P` option but both behaves the same.

Please let me know on how ti fix this error.

Comment: Why don't you generate your cscope database from the root of your project?

Comment: More references will be thrown to the same text/variable search, if the cscope db is generated from root, I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out later that its nothing to do with relative path, if the file is in dos line ending format, it is not displayed in cscope window. Use '!dos2unix %' from vi to overcome this error.